# What's the process of uploading an excel sheet to an external API using JQuery/Node?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, excel, express

If I have an excel sheet that I want to submit to an API endpoint that requires the headers:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileData"; filename="Form_SOMETHING(1).xlsx"
```

Am I able to make an AJAX request using JQuery to the endpoint to send this file or do I need to do specific processing in express before I can ship it off?

I've never done this before so I'm just looking for a direction to go since all the examples I have seen pass the excel to an angular controller or php service beforehand and I'm just dealing with JQuery and express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to consider a different approach. If this service lives on another domain you are going to have cross domain issues with jquery. You may be able to use just a straight `<form>` with the POST method. If you are able to pass a redirect URL in the POST params that it would be easy.

If you provide more info on the endpoint, I can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: I have the ability to POST to the other domain to avoid the CORs error, but the service does live on another domain.  The only requirement for the service is those headers mentioned above.

Comment: You could use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) depending on what browsers you support. Alternatively, you could use a hidden form and just trigger the submit from jquery.

Comment: Okay, this should work for containing the input file data and FormData works for my browser requirements!  If I can get it to go through I'll accept your answer, thank you Daniel